# sentry android install error Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0

Tags: android, kotlin, sentry

i want to add sentry 5.6.0 to my android project but always give error on `gradle` build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "io.sentry.android.gradle" version "3.0.0"
}
apply plugin: 'io.sentry.android.gradle'
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:5.6.0'
}
```

i have two `build.gradle` and other file has below lines

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://github.com/akapelrud/Rotary-Seekbar/raw/master/RotaryKnob/snapshots' }
    }
}
```

this is part of my `gradle.build` file and using kotlin and `minSdk 19` `tagetSdk 32`

Comment: Hey, sorry that you are having troubles. Are you sure you have `google()` in your `allprojects { repositories { }}` block? This dependency comes from the google maven repository, so it has to be declared somewhere

Comment: thanks for answer. i create project with android studio and nowhere has not this code you write. what file i must add codes to it?

Comment: `build.gradle` in the root of your project, there should be `allprojects` block

Comment: i think it`s already exists. however project is public on https://github.com/motad333/sms_app .
you can see and help.
thanks

Comment: Hm, I have just checked out your project and was able to build it without any changes (only uncommenting the `io.sentry:sentry-android` dependency). Could you try maybe to run the build from terminal/commandline like `./gradlew assembleDebug --refresh-dependencies`